# System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.' C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo aquí el siguiente método que al dar clic en alguna fila me muestra un pequeño mensaje indicando cuando fue la utlima vez que se atendio.

```
private void DataGridHisPac_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dataGridHisPac.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["hISCLIFECACTDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == DBNull.Value || dataGridHisPac.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["hISCLIFECACTDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == null)
            {
                DateTime tmpFecEla = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridHisPac.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["hISCLIFECELADataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString());
                lblFecAct.Text = "No ha tenido ningún avance clínico desde su 1era Visita el : " + Convert.ToString(tmpFecEla.ToString("dd") + " de " + Convert.ToString(tmpFecEla.ToString("MMMM") + " de " + Convert.ToString(tmpFecEla.ToString("yyyy"))));
            }
            else
            {
                DateTime tmpFecAct = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridHisPac.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["hISCLIFECACTDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString());
                lblFecAct.Text = "Su última atención clínica fue el: " + Convert.ToString(tmpFecAct.ToString("dd") + " de " + Convert.ToString(tmpFecAct.ToString("MMMM") + " de " + Convert.ToString(tmpFecAct.ToString("yyyy"))));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Aquí el método de búsqueda.

```
List<Buscar_Paciente_Nombre_Historial_Clinico> Paciente_Nombre = null;
    List<Buscar_Paciente_Apellido_Historial_Clinico> Paciente_Apellido = null;
    int var_boo = 0;
    private void TxtBusqueda_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridHisPac.DataSource = null;
        List<Buscar_Paciente_Nombre_Historial_Clinico> Pac_Nom_Fil = new List<Buscar_Paciente_Nombre_Historial_Clinico>();

        List<Buscar_Paciente_Apellido_Historial_Clinico> Pac_Ape_Fil = new List<Buscar_Paciente_Apellido_Historial_Clinico>();
        
        if (txtBusqueda.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            dataGridHisPac.DataSource = daoHisCli.Cargar_Historial_Clinico();
        }
        else if (txtBusqueda.Text.Length < 3)
        {
            Paciente_Nombre = null;
            Paciente_Apellido = null;
            return;
        }
        else if (txtBusqueda.Text.Length == 3 && rdbApe.Checked == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(txtBusqueda.Text.Length);
            var_boo = 1;
            Paciente_Apellido = Buscar_Paciente_Apellido_Historial_Clinico.Busqueda_Paciente_Apellido(txtBusqueda.Text);
            Pac_Ape_Fil = Paciente_Apellido;
            Console.WriteLine(txtBusqueda.Text);
            Console.WriteLine("CONDICION =>"+var_boo);
        }
        else if (txtBusqueda.Text.Length == 3 && rdbCed.Checked == true)
        {
            var_boo = 2;
            Paciente_Nombre = Buscar_Paciente_Nombre_Historial_Clinico.Busqueda_Paciente_Nombre(txtBusqueda.Text);
            Pac_Nom_Fil = Paciente_Nombre;
            Console.WriteLine(txtBusqueda.Text);
            Console.WriteLine("CONDICION =>" + var_boo);
        }
        else
        {
            if (var_boo == 1)
            {
               Pac_Ape_Fil = Paciente_Apellido.FindAll(x => x.NOMPAC.Contains(txtBusqueda.Text));
                dataGridHisPac.DataSource = Pac_Ape_Fil;
            }
            else if (var_boo == 2)
            {
                Pac_Nom_Fil = Paciente_Nombre.FindAll(x => x.NOMPAC.Contains(txtBusqueda.Text));
                dataGridHisPac.DataSource = Pac_Nom_Fil;
            }
        }
    }
```

El problema reside que cuando realizo una búsqueda en base al criterio de apellido o nombre al momento de dar un clic y ver la informacion de esa fila seleccionada me arroja el siguiente mensaje que muestro por imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicional revisando mas a fondo veo que el problema viene desde que realizo la búsqueda ya que en ciertos campos mas específicamente `HISCLI_FEC_ACT` en algunos casos no tiene datos como se ve en la imagen que adjunto.

```
public static List<Buscar_Paciente_Apellido_Historial_Clinico> Busqueda_Paciente_Apellido(String Nom_Pac)
    {
        List<Buscar_Paciente_Apellido_Historial_Clinico> listHc = new List<Buscar_Paciente_Apellido_Historial_Clinico>();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand sql;
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter1;
        String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            sql = new SqlCommand("Buscar_Paciente_Apellido_Historial_Clinico", conn);
            Console.WriteLine(sql);
            if (conn != null)
            {
                sqlDataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NOMPACHISCLI", Nom_Pac));
                sqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sql;
                sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dt);
            }
            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                Buscar_Paciente_Apellido_Historial_Clinico dsr = new Buscar_Paciente_Apellido_Historial_Clinico
                {
                    HISCLI_COD = r["HISCLI_COD"].ToString(),
                    HISCLI_COD_ODONT = r["HISCLI_COD_ODONT"].ToString(),
                    NOMODONT = r["NOMODONT"].ToString(),
                    HISCLI_COD_PAC = r["HISCLI_COD_PAC"].ToString(),
                    NOMPAC = r["NOMPAC"].ToString(),
                    HISCLI_MOT_CON = r["HISCLI_MOT_CON"].ToString(),
                    HISCLI_FEC_ELA = Convert.ToDateTime(r["HISCLI_FEC_ELA"]),
                    HISCLI_FEC_ACT = Convert.ToDateTime(r["HISCLI_FEC_ACT"])
                };
                listHc.Add(dsr);
            }
            return listHc;
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que podría estar realizando de manera errónea, o como podría controlar o evitar desde que hago la búsqueda no caiga en error en base al null que me va a arrojar en ciertos casos porque la columna `HISCLI_FEC_ACT` no contiene datos

Comment: No son muchas líneas las que pueden estar causando el problema. Sería más fácil si cargaras el error completo. Ahí dice dónde ocurre.

Comment: @Mateo añadí mas código porque resulta que el problema era un poco mas a fondo cuando esta null en la fecha de actualización me arroja ese error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema puede ser la otra fecha que no se esta validando si es null, podrias intentar con este codigo:

```
private void DataGridHisPac_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (dataGridHisPac.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["hISCLIFECACTDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == DBNull.Value || dataGridHisPac.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["hISCLIFECACTDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == null)
        {               
            if(!(dataGridHisPac.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["hISCLIFECELADataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == DBNull.Value || dataGridHisPac.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["hISCLIFECELADataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == null)){
                DateTime tmpFecEla = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridHisPac.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["hISCLIFECELADataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString());
                lblFecAct.Text = "No ha tenido ningún avance clínico desde su 1era Visita el : " + Convert.ToString(tmpFecEla.ToString("dd") + " de " + Convert.ToString(tmpFecEla.ToString("MMMM") + " de " + Convert.ToString(tmpFecEla.ToString("yyyy"))));              
            }else{
                lblFecAct.Text = "No ha tenido ningún avance clínico desde NUNCA porque no hay valor en el campu hISCLIFECELADataGridViewTextBoxColumn";//Este mensaje se debe cambiar obviamente
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime tmpFecAct = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridHisPac.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["hISCLIFECACTDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString());
            lblFecAct.Text = "Su última atención clínica fue el: " + Convert.ToString(tmpFecAct.ToString("dd") + " de " + Convert.ToString(tmpFecAct.ToString("MMMM") + " de " + Convert.ToString(tmpFecAct.ToString("yyyy"))));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```